# mysql conditional subquery with joins or case

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, mariadb, subquery

I have 3 tables `Project`, `ProjectLikes` and `User`.

When a logged in user is browsing through the list of `Projects` I have to identify if the current user *liked* the project i.e there is a row storing user id, project id in `ProjectLikes` table.

But i don't know how to do it.
This is how i do it to fetch the projects. I can't figure out how to solve this.

```
SELECT 
   id,
   title,
   createdAt,
FROM
   Project
ORDER BY 
   createdAt desc 
LIMIT 10
```

In `ProjectLikes` i am storing project id and user id.
and the output that i want is an additional row which says this project is liked by the user (i already have the user id since user is logged in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `exists`:

```
select p.*, 
    (exists (select 1 from projetlikes pl where pl.projectid = p.id and pl.userid = ?)) is_liked_by_user
from project p
```

This adds a `0`/`1` value to each row that indicates whether the current user likes the project. This assumes that table `projectlikes` has columns `projectid`  and `userid`. The id of the logged in user is represented by `?` in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
   id,
   title,
   createdAt,
   CASE WHEN ProjectLikes.project_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS liked
FROM
   Project
LEFT JOIN ProjectLikes 
    ON ProjectLikes.project_id = Project.id AND ProjectLikes.user_id = <USER_ID> 
ORDER BY 
   createdAt desc 
LIMIT 10
```